# Deploying node.js lambda with AWS CDK python

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I try to deploy node.js lambda function with CDK python. Unfortunately, I cannot find any tutorials for this combination. Here is what I did.

```
mkdir hello
cd hello
cdk init app --language python
virtualenv -p python3.7 env
source env/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
(edit ./app.py and ./code/hello.js)
cdk diff
```

Then I got the following error. How can I solve this problem?

```
  File "app.py", line 24, in <module>
    HelloStack(app, "HelloStack")
  File "/home/bitnami/hello/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_runtime.py", line 86, in __call__
    inst = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "app.py", line 20, in __init__
    entry="./code/hello.js"
  File "/home/bitnami/hello/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_runtime.py", line 86, in __call__
    inst = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bitnami/hello/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aws_cdk/aws_lambda_nodejs/__init__.py", line 1307, in __init__
    jsii.create(self.__class__, self, [scope, id, props])
  File "/home/bitnami/hello/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/__init__.py", line 297, in create
    for iface in getattr(klass, "__jsii_ifaces__", [])
  File "/home/bitnami/hello/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 344, in create
    return self._process.send(request, CreateResponse)
  File "/home/bitnami/hello/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 326, in send
    raise JSIIError(resp.error) from JavaScriptError(resp.stack)
jsii.errors.JSIIError: Cannot find a package lock file (`pnpm-lock.yaml`, `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json`). Please specify it with `depsLockFilePath`.
```

Here are the files.

app.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

import aws_cdk as cdk

from aws_cdk import (
    # Duration,
    Stack,
    aws_lambda_nodejs as lamjs,
)
from constructs import Construct

class HelloStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        helloFn = lamjs.NodejsFunction(
          self,"hello",
          entry="./code/hello.js"
        );

app = cdk.App()
HelloStack(app, "HelloStack")
app.synth()
```

code/hello.js

```
exports.handler = async(event, context) => {
    return 1;
};
```

Here is my environment.

```
cdk --version
2.24.1 (build 585f9ca)
npm --version
6.14.15
```

--- Update on May 25, 2022 ---

I added the following package.json in the hello directory and ran "npm install".

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hello",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "bin": {
    "hello": "code/hello.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "test": "jest",
    "cdk": "cdk"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.0",
    "@types/node": "10.17.27",
    "@types/prettier": "2.6.0",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.4",
    "aws-cdk": "2.24.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-cdk-lib": "2.24.1",
    "constructs": "^10.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21"
  }
}
```

This makes package-lock.json and then I ran "cdk diff". Then I got the following error.

```
jsii.errors.JavaScriptError:
  Error: spawnSync docker ENOMEM
      at Object.spawnSync (internal/child_process.js:1077:20)
      at Object.spawnSync (child_process.js:776:24)
      at dockerExec (/tmp/jsii-kernel-LhoMqm/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/bundling.js:1:4968)
      at Function.fromBuild (/tmp/jsii-kernel-LhoMqm/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/bundling.js:1:3553)
      at new Bundling (/tmp/jsii-kernel-LhoMqm/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-nodejs/lib/bundling.js:1:2057)
      at Function.bundle (/tmp/jsii-kernel-LhoMqm/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-nodejs/lib/bundling.js:1:2947)
      at new NodejsFunction (/tmp/jsii-kernel-LhoMqm/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-nodejs/lib/function.js:1:1361)
      at /tmp/tmp5utwlvy5/lib/program.js:8420:58
      at Kernel._wrapSandboxCode (/tmp/tmp5utwlvy5/lib/program.js:8848:24)
      at Kernel._create (/tmp/tmp5utwlvy5/lib/program.js:8420:34)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 24, in <module>
    HelloStack(app, "HelloStack")
  File "/home/bitnami/hello/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_runtime.py", line 86, in __call__
    inst = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "app.py", line 20, in __init__
    entry="./code/hello.js"
  File "/home/bitnami/hello/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_runtime.py", line 86, in __call__
    inst = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bitnami/hello/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aws_cdk/aws_lambda_nodejs/__init__.py", line 1307, in __init__
    jsii.create(self.__class__, self, [scope, id, props])
  File "/home/bitnami/hello/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/__init__.py", line 297, in create
    for iface in getattr(klass, "__jsii_ifaces__", [])
  File "/home/bitnami/hello/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 344, in create
    return self._process.send(request, CreateResponse)
  File "/home/bitnami/hello/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 326, in send
    raise JSIIError(resp.error) from JavaScriptError(resp.stack)
jsii.errors.JSIIError: spawnSync docker ENOMEM
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Sorry for my late reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs-readme.html#lock-file):

> The NodejsFunction requires a dependencies lock file (yarn.lock, pnpm-lock.yaml or package-lock.json). When bundling in a Docker container, the path containing this lock file is used as the source (/asset-input) for the volume mounted in the container.

So you would need your lambda folder to have a lock file in one of the supported formats.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the question. After I added package-lock.json, I got the new error.

Comment: That's a different and unrelated issue. You're running out of memory. Why do you need to install CDK inside the lambda?